# Shuffling a vector in Javascript until there are a set number of nonrepeating elements?

Tags: javascript, random, vector

I have a randomly generated vector of 1s and 2s, which I want to continuously reshuffle until I have a set number of 'switches'. For example, if vec = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1], then there are four 'switches' (elements that don't match the previous element, discounting the first element in the vector). I want to reshuffle this vector until I have, say, exactly three switches.

Right now, I'm using a while loop that counts the number of switches via an embedded for loop (which cycles through each element in the vector, checking whether that element is equal to the previous element, and incrementing the counter if not) The while loop terminates once the counter hits the appropriate value. This works, but it's really inefficient -- it can take several minutes to run (using a full vector = 480 elements, aiming for exactly 160 switches).

Any advice re: coding this more efficiently would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that the long time it is taking is actually due to you waiting for your desired state to occur randomly via repeated shuffling. The part of the code that checks for the "switches" is likely not what is causing the long runtime.

Comment: how many different items do you have in your 480 elements array?

Comment: There are two unique items in the array -- the only possible values are 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I spent a long time thinking of a solution to this problem originally but honestly my solution was very hacky. Here is a much cleaner and far better solution that does the random partitions more accurately, and is guaranteed to terminate (which the other technically isn't.)

```js
function get_random_int(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function count_switches(arr) {
    let switches = 0;
    let prev = arr[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        switches += arr[i] != prev;
        prev = arr[i];
    }
    return switches;
}

function generate_partitions(total, splits) {
    if (splits > total) return [];
    const split_arr = Array(splits + 1).fill(1);
    for (let i = 0; i < total - splits; i++) {
        split_arr[get_random_int(0, splits)]++;
    }
    return split_arr;
}

function generate_splits(vec_length, num_splits) {
    const partitions = generate_partitions(vec_length, num_splits);
    const splits = [];
    let curr_val = get_random_int(1, 2);
    partitions.forEach((partition) => {
        splits.push(...Array(partition).fill(curr_val));
        curr_val = 3 - curr_val;
    });
    return splits;
}

let output = generate_splits(480, 160);
console.log(output, count_switches(output), 'switches counted!');
```

The basic idea is: figure out how many `1`s and `2`s we want, calculate how many consecutive "runs" of each we need (i.e. 1111222211 is two runs of `1`s and one run of `2`s), then calculate how long each run will be with some random partitioning. Please note that the partitioning is slightly biased. Randomly dividing a number `n` into `k` positive integers is a very hard problem, but this should be decently random depending on your application.

Please let me know if you want me to explain any part of this code better!

```js
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    
    function shuffleArray(array) {
        for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    
    function count_switches(arr) {
        let switches = 0;
        let last = arr[0];
        for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            if (arr[i] != last) {
                switches += 1;
                last = arr[i];
            }
        }
        
        return switches;
    }
    
    function generate_partitions(total, splits) {
      while(true) {
        let randoms = [];
        for (let _ = 0; _ < splits; _++) {
          randoms.push(Math.random());
        }
        let randoms_sum = randoms.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
        for (let i = 0; i < splits; ++i) {
          randoms[i] = Math.floor((randoms[i] / randoms_sum) * total)
        }
        randoms_sum = randoms.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    
        for (let _ = 0; _ < total - randoms_sum; ++_) {
          if (randoms.includes(0)) {
            randoms[randoms.indexOf(0)]++;
          } else {
            randoms[getRandomInt(0, splits - 1)]++;
          }
        }
    
        if (!randoms.includes(0)) {
          shuffleArray(randoms);
          return randoms;
        }
      }    
    }
    
    function generate_splits(vec_length, num_splits) {
      let num_ones = 0, num_twos = 0;
      while(true) {
        num_ones = getRandomInt(0, vec_length);
        num_twos = vec_length - num_ones;
        if (Math.min(num_ones, num_twos) * 2 >= num_splits) {
          break;
        }
      }
    
      let num_one_runs = Math.floor((num_splits + 1) / 2);
      let num_two_runs = num_one_runs;
      if (num_splits % 2 == 0) {
        if (Math.random() > .5) {
          num_one_runs += 1;
        } else {
           num_two_runs += 1;
        }
      }
    
      let one_run_partitions = generate_partitions(num_ones, num_one_runs), two_run_partitions = generate_partitions(num_twos, num_two_runs)
    
      let first = one_run_partitions, first_output = 1
      let second = two_run_partitions, second_output = 2
      if (one_run_partitions.length < two_run_partitions.length || (one_run_partitions.length == two_run_partitions.length && Math.random() > .5)) {
        first = two_run_partitions, first_output = 2
        second = one_run_partitions, second_output = 1
      }
      const output = []
      for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(num_one_runs, num_two_runs); ++i) {
        for (let _ = 0; _ < first[i]; ++_) {
          output.push(first_output);
        }
        if (i < second.length) {
          for (let _ = 0; _ < second[i]; ++_) {
            output.push(second_output);
          }
        }
      }
      return output;
      
    }
    
    let output = generate_splits(480, 160);
    console.log(output, count_switches(output));
```

Example of heavily biased outputs with 380 1's, 100 2's, and 160 switches. Runtime was `0m0.045s`:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! My Python is really weak, but I'll step my way through this and see whether I can translate it to Javascript.

Comment: I am working on translating this into Javascript. It was unfair of me to write this in the language you did not ask for.

Comment: @0demo1 I have translated this into Javascript. I hope it works for you! It still runs in less than a second.

Comment: You're welcome! It was an interesting problem to think about. Would you mind explaining briefly what this helps you solve? I am curious what application this has.

Comment: For sure! This is for an experiment requiring participants to switch between two categorization tasks (task 1 and task 2) trial-by-trial. I'm interested in how participants' performance (e.g., accuracy; reaction time) is impacted on 'switch trials' (where trial N is task 1 and trial N-1 was task 2, or vice versa) relative to 'stay trials' (where both trial N and trial N-1 are task 1, or both are task 2). Ideally, switches should be somewhat rare -- here, occurring on 1/3 of all trials -- so that participants don't expect to constantly switch! I'm using this vector to determine trial order.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the wanted count of switches, generate an array of indices for the switches, like

```
                v  v  v  v  v
indices   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
values   [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
switches    0  0  1  1  1  1
indices           2  3  4  5
fill1           1  2  1  2  1
fill2           2  1  2  1  2
```

and fill the array with values.

The check the result and repeat, if necessary.

```js
function disperse(a, b, switches) {
    const
        count = c => v => c[v]--,
        size = a + b - 1;

    do {
        const indices = new Set;
            
        while (indices.size < switches) indices.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * size));

        let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;

        const result = Array.from(
            { length: a + b },
            (_, i) => indices.has(i - 1)
                ? (value = { 1: 2, 2: 1 }[value])
                : value
        );
        if (result.every(count({ 1: a, 2: b }))) return result;
    } while (true);
    return [];
}

console.log(...disperse(5, 3, 4));
```

Comment: Running this code on inputs of the size that OP was describing (`a` and `b` sum to 480, and there are 160 splits) with an imbalance of 1's and 2's causes this code to take a very long time. If `a` and `b` are both 240, the code runs almost instantly. If `a=380`and `b=100` the code runs for minutes in my testing.

Comment: right. it's a problem.

Comment: Thanks very much! This is a little slower than I needed it to be -- but still faster than what I had before, haha. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a switch as a sequence of same-value elements of a random length. Then your vector as a sum of those switches.

In other words, if you want `S` switches, you need to split your vector to `S + 1` random length parts, and fill those parts with `1` or `2` correspondingly.

```js
const f = (V, S) => {
  // V - vector length
  // S - number of switches

  if (V - S <= 0) return 'Vector cannot fit all the switches';

  const Vector = Array.from(Array(V).keys());

  // setting random switch points on the vector
  for (let i = 0; i < S; ++i) {
    const r = Math.random() * (V - i - 2) + i + 1 | 0;
    [Vector[i], Vector[r]] = [Vector[r], Vector[i]];
  }  
  const switchPoints = Vector.slice(0, S).sort((a, b) => b - a);
  
  let state = Math.random() > .5; // initial switch state
  let p = switchPoints.pop();
  Vector.forEach((e, i, a) => {
    if (i === p) {
      state = !state;
      p = switchPoints.pop();
    }
    a[i] = 1 + state;
  });
  return Vector;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(4, 1)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(5, 5)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(480, 160)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(48000, 16000)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; overflow:auto !important}
```

Comment: I would need to think about this approach more, but I think it would be a lot better if you shuffled the `switchlength` runs around more. If you look at the output it's almost always large runs at the start and then at the end just alternating 1s and 2s to make the invariant hold which doesn't feel like the spirit OP was going for.

Comment: @JRose, it's Math.random, pseudo-random number with approximately uniform distribution over the range. I believe it's not guaranteed that `it's almost always large runs at the start and then at the end just alternating 1s and 2s to make the invariant`

Comment: You are technically correct. It is not guaranteed that the output will look like this. However, because you are generating numbers in a progressively smaller and smaller range, the end of your array ends up almost always being alternating 1s and 2s. Just run the code you posted a dozen times to see that I am not exaggerating.

Comment: Thank you both!! This is very close to what I'm looking for, but as JRose notes, I'd like to avoid the high probability of long runs at the start and alternation at the end (ideally, I'd like both long runs AND element-by-element alternation to be relatively rare, although of course they'll sometimes occur).

Comment: @0demo1, thanks, I've updated my answer to equalize the probabilities.